# Windows 7 migrate to smaller SSD by disk copy

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have following scenario.

Windows 7 with 1 TB disk, shrink-ed to about 500 GB. Used space is 200 GB.
I am trying to consolidate free space, but it does not seems to work beyond 500 GB.

Windows 7 have small empty partition 100 MB in front of the big one.
(similar to Linux's `/boot` ?)

Windows 7 is NOT UEFI Boot (system have legacy boot) and 500 GB partition is marked as `active`

SSD 250 GB

I have Linux running where I can attach both disks.
Can I migrate the data somehow with copy (from Linux), so at the end Windows 7 to be able to boot from the SSD.

I know I can do it if it were Linux, but I have no idea how Windows 7 boots and what I need to `dd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it 3 days later :)

I tried several times with Microsof Defrag, using `-X` option. Unfortunately it does not worked.

Then after a backup, I installed `Auslogics Defrag Free`. I found out, that this program can not consolidate the disk space. However it show very clear what files are positioned at the end of the disk.

Since I am lazy and did not wanted to clear all files by hand, I installed `Auslogics Defrag (Paid)`. But I found it still have no free space consolidation until you actually pay.

Finally, I installed `Perfect Disk` trial. This program consolidated the space.

Finally I shrink the disk and `dd` it to the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Is the remaining space unallocated?

Sounds like you need to go to System Management > Disk Management
and partition the rest of the hdd

hope this helps

Comment: defrag /x not seems to consolidate everything. shrink stays at '600 GB'

Comment: @Nick tried disabling pagefile (virtual memory) and `powercfg /h off` before defrag?

Comment: yes, i did this

Answer (score 0):

You can backup the 1 TB disk and restore to SSD.

Be sure to include System partition as well as OS partition in backup.

I have used the free tool [Macrium reflect](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx), there are other free tools offering same functionality. Be sure to **select the option to backup only occupied by files partition space**.

During backup disk contents is compressed so you need far less than 200 GB on external media for storing the backup. You can even do the backup to your 1 TB disk (in the freed space).

As a bonus you will have a complete backup of your system so you can restore in case of system failure.

Just a suggestion - there are relatively cheap external USB 3.0 disks for backup. You can even install to and start Windows 10 from such a disk (newer Windows versions can easily be installed to USB drives, aka Windows 2 Go).